# Linux Kernel - Refreshing VFS Dentry Cache

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I wrote a system call that opens a directory and gets the file object and the dentry struct. Im trying to list all entries including entries in subdirectories using the list_for_each() macro. The problem is its only displaying whats currently in the dentry cache. If I open the directory with nautilus then rerun the system call, all the entries are listed. Is there a way to check the exact list of entries or refresh the cache?

```
f = s_open(tpath);

fle = fget(f);
d = fle->f_path.dentry;
list_for_each ( dentry ) {   
    ...
}
sys_close(f);
```

Comment: Is there some particular reason that you are _not_ doing this in user space?

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using a system call to read the contents of a directory? It sounds like you really should be in userland, and that you should then be using something like opendir.